# Why is it considered bad table design to use multiple tables in dynamodb?

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I was wondering why I keep reading that the correct implementation of a nosql database only involves one table (in most cases). I have a use-case which has some kind of hierarchy which can be implemented in a single table, but it is currently being implemented using a lot more tables. The number of read/writes is the same in both implementations (I think at least) so I don't get why I should bother trying to implement my database using only one table

I get that data shouldn't be normalised in a nosql database, but why should that mean that I shouldn't use multiple tables? Is it just because it costs more to maintain multiple tables and I should instead resort to using a single table with multiple GSIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this statement about single table was taken out of [the context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html) and overhyped recently. No one forces you to use as many tables as you want. You don't pay for the number of tables in DynamoDB, only for data stored and queried, so there are no extra costs for extra tables. Finally, DynamoDB is fully managed solution and having 100 tables is as easy as having one.

The idea is that unlike RDBMS that force normalization of data you should not use multiple tables for *related* entries. Usually, because, you know, "there are no joins in NoSQL". Orders with multiple order line items, departments and employees – data like that can be put in a single table, indeed. Even in a single item (but always remember about [item size limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items)).

One more thing about "single table" desing: it requires your to know in advance about the data you'll store inside and the queries you'll run against it.

But imagine a table that is used to store both your clients' orders and your employees (when the question is not "how much orders do my sales do?"). There is no point in that schema at all: you can just use two tables for that. A table that stores all you data is a ["god object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) (or "god table"). And it's an anti-patter: it is tricky to query from console and code, it is tricky to understand it's purpose and it's almost impossible to expand when you'll have your requirements changed (adding another kind of records or new query / usage pattern).